# card view elevation not showing up

Tags: android

There are many questions about cardview elevation here and i tried all the solution to solve the problem but it is still not working.  I have added             card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" into cardview and i have also tried to set hardware acceleration to true in android manifest. I also read that if i use padding in cardview it might cut out the shadows for card view. can someone let me know what am i doing wrong. I can see the shadows in android studio but not on the emulator or real device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            >

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/horizontal_spacing">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/aboutpallogo"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:textColor="#171652"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Header"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    android:textColor="#4cbea9"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"/>

                <com.mediamer.apps.pal_library.helpers.ExpandableTextView
                    android:id="@+id/expandableTextView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    app:expanded="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
                    />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/report_details_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You just have to replace

```
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
  card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
  card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

with

```
  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
  app:cardElevation="6dp"
```

Now you are good to go. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
android:elevation="6dp"
```

in

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

section. Also the information of how are you using this Cardview may be useful.

Comment: i am using cardview in gridview. I also created another activity and tried to put the cardview to test it and see if the gridview is the reason why the shadow is not showing up, but it didnt work as well